# Bit Masks: Set different states of an object via set method

Tags: c++, class, set, bit-manipulation, member

I have a material which can be either HOT or COLD, WHITE or BLACK. The states can be HOT and WHITE, HOT and BLACK, COLD and WHITE, COLD and BLACK. I have the following class

```
   class myMaterial
    {
    public:
        enum state
        {
            DEFAULT     = 0,
            HOT         = 1 << 0,
            WHITE       = 1 << 1
        };

        void SetState(int);

    private:
        int m_state;
    };


    void myMaterial::SetState(int state)
    {
        m_state = state;
    }
```

Now in main(), I call the SetState method to set these states

```
myMaterial material;
material.SetState(myMaterial::HOT);
```

Is the following bitwise operations correct, to set all the types of states

```
HOT and WHITE  =>  myMaterial::HOT | myMaterial::WHITE
HOT and BLACK  =>  myMaterial::HOT | ~myMaterial::WHITE
COLD and WHITE =>  ~myMaterial::HOT | myMaterial::WHITE
COLD and BLACK =>  ~myMaterial::HOT | ~myMaterial::WHITE
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish exactly? The list of types of states doesn't seem to make sense: you can't have *just* `HOT` - the color bit must have *some* value, be it 0 or 1.

Comment: My bad. I will edit the question

Answer (score 1):

No.

Using `~` means negating all the bits; which I suppose is not what you want, as it results in lots and lots of 1s in your representation (all except one single bit).
You're having 3 states for each status, for example cold, hot, and don't know. So you'll need 2 bits for them, not 1.

**Edit**

Now the question is changed, but if we assume you still have 3 states for each bit, you will need two bits. So assume you have a `COLD` and `HOT` state. Then:

```
HOT = 1 << 0;
COLD = 1 << 1;
```

And then if you want to set the variable `var` to `COLD`, making sure it's not `HOT`, you'll need to do:

```
var = (var | COLD) // add coldness
var = var & ~HOT // remove hotness
```

Or equivalently:

```
var = (var | COLD) & ~HOT
```

Answer (score 1):

After the edit, the question seems to be a little different, and doesn't require @adrin's solution of 2 bits per property any more.

Now it's just:

```
HOT and WHITE = myMaterial::HOT | myMaterial::WHITE
HOT and BLACK = myMaterial::HOT
COLD and WHITE = myMaterial::WHITE
COLD and BLACK = 0
```

If you add an extra bit that says whether the state is known or not:

```
UNKNOWN = 0
HOT and WHITE = myMaterial::HOT | myMaterial::WHITE | myMaterial::KNOWN
HOT and BLACK = myMaterial::HOT | myMaterial::KNOWN
COLD and WHITE = myMaterial::WHITE | myMaterial::KNOWN
COLD and BLACK =  myMaterial::KNOWN
```

Comment: If I have another state which is unknown to me (denoted by DEFAULT, used the wrong word :(), how do I set that? Should I assign DEFAULT a negative number instead of zero?

Comment: @ontherocks you could make it work with a negative number. You could also add a bit to says whether the state is known or not.

Comment: If I use `DEFAULT = 1 << 0, HOT = 1 << 1, WHITE = 1 << 2`, how do I set COLD and BLACK now? It will still be zero?

Comment: @ontherocks it's probably more convenient to use 0 as the "unknown" state, so I based my edit on that

Comment: @ontherocks the bit indicating that the material and colour are not default

Comment: Still confused. So my enum would look now, `enum state{UNKNOWN = 0, KNOWN = 1, HOT = 1 << 1, WHITE = 1 << 2};`?

Comment: @ontherocks sure, for example.